# Header and Footer on multipage listoffigures

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, fancyhdr

I've using the [fancyhdr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package to modify the header and footer. If my `\listoffigures` spans multiple pages then the header and footer on page one of the LoF is not fancy. The TeX example below demonstrates this.

What am I doing wrong please?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[a3paper,landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{A}
\fancyhead[C]{FANCY}
\fancyhead[R]{HEADER}

\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[L]{A}
\fancyfoot[C]{FANCY}
\fancyfoot[R]{FOOTER}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures\thispagestyle{fancy}

\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage
\begin{figure}[p]\begin{center}qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{center}\end{figure}\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\listoffigures` processes the entire list before `\thispagestyle{fancy}` is seen.  the change of style needs to be made before that, probably within the definition of `\listoffigures`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Instead of `\begin{center}...\end{center}` you could use just `\centering ...` in the `figure` environment.

Comment: Indeed -- see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables

Comment: @Stephen Thanks for the \centering command.

Comment: @barbara beeton Thanks for the response.  I only notice this issue when the LoF went over two pages.  The following example does appear to honor the \thispagestyle{fancy} command: `\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{A}
\fancyhead[C]{FANCY}
\fancyhead[R]{HEADER}

\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[L]{A}
\fancyfoot[C]{FANCY}
\fancyfoot[R]{FOOTER}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures\thispagestyle{fancy}

\begin{figure}[p]\centering qwerty\caption{qwerty}\end{figure}\clearpage

\end{document}`

Comment: Apologies, I don't know how to post a code snippet in reply comment, so have stuck it on paste bin here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=rtJ0NQaC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first page in a chapter (and also of the list of figures, which internally uses `\chapter`) use the plain pagestyle. So you need to redefine it: add

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhead{}
  \fancyhead[L]{A}
  \fancyhead[C]{FANCY}
  \fancyhead[R]{HEADER}

  \fancyfoot{}
  \fancyfoot[L]{A}
  \fancyfoot[C]{FANCY}
  \fancyfoot[R]{FOOTER}
}
```

after the similar settings you already do.

If the two page styles are really identical, then saying

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy
\makeatother
```

will make calling the `plain` page style equivalent to calling the `fancy` page style. With the method of redefining the `plain` style described above you get much more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Chapter 7 of the [fancyhdr user manual](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf=fancyhdr) talks about this plain style.  Is there a way I can copy my fancy style to plain, without having to repeat all the commands?  Something like plain = fancy, instead of two identical definitions, one for fancy, one for plain?

Comment: @chris Added the "simpler way".